# Non-zero exist status and permission denied trying to install application in Plesk 10

Tags: wordpress, plesk

I am using Plesk Panel 10.4.4 on an Ubuntu server and trying to install WordPress. I continue to get "Non-zero exit status returned by script" and "failed to open stream: Permission denied" warnings.

Do I need to change permissions so that the Plesk portal can make these changes? I would like to be able to install applications through Plesk in the future.

Comment: Do you have control of the VPS/Server that you're installing it on? You may want to try logging in with elevated privileges if possible.

Comment: Are you installing Wordpress from the original distribution or you run pre-packed Wordpress application (Plesk has built-in app installer)?